# Can you edit padding parameters for RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: vb.net, random, cryptography, rsa, padding

I'm writing an RSA encryption code on vb.net using the RSACryptoServiceProvider class. You get the option to use pkcs v1.5 or OAEP padding but i can't understand if it's parameters can be shown or are accessible to edit. I've seen the RSAOAEPKeyExchangeFormatter Class and RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter classes but i don't know how to use them. 
Is it possible to edit the parameter for the padded bytes and import padding bytes from your own random byte generator? 
Is there a sample code which does that, that i could view and understand the procedure? 
In general can the padding parameters on RSACryptoServiceProvider class be changed?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're asking to provide your own Random Number Generator to be used inside `RSAOAEPKeyExchangeFormatter` and others, so that it can result in a deterministic padding, right? I don't think it's possible, but there may be workarounds. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to be able to edit some or all of the parameters used for padding. This is for a personal project with minimum encryption bits and advanced stealth. Basically i want to create another encryption algorithm based on rsa. If this cannot be done through the .net classes how else could be done? Is re writing the padding code an option?

Comment: I think you would need to write quite a lot. Anyway, the source code is available ([example](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsaoaepkeyexchangeformatter.cs,be7f35735c80cc2b)), so you can try it out.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, .NET does not expose the underlying data padders for RSA, nor does it support raw RSA encryption (for you to have pre-defined the padding).

The only way to accomplish what you've asked is to find a 3rd party implementation of RSA, write RSA yourself (usually considered a Bad Idea), or do a p/invoke into the underlying Windows CAPI or CNG encryption routines (e.g. [NCryptEncrypt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376255(v=vs.85).aspx)) to perform a padding-free RSA encryption.